# What is the reference of "an hour-long attraction" in this paragraph?

Tags: meaning

In this paragraph:

> The demise of cine-variety and the decline in weekly attendances from
> 110 to 60 million between 1930 and 1933 prompted the decision to add
> **an hour-long attraction** to the cartoons, newsreels and shorts already
> supporting the big picture in order to offer value for money to
> matinee patrons who often preferred quantity to quality.

As I understand, demise of cine-variety and decline attendances has caused somebody (or a system) adds an hour-long attraction to the cartoons, newsreels and shorts. But I can't understand what is exactly this "an hour-long attraction".

Comment: It's about cinemas. A film lasting one hour.

Answer (score 1):

It's often helpful to look to the immediately surrounding context. We are adding this "hour-long attraction" to "cartoons, newsreels and shorts" as well as a "big picture," in order to "offer value for money to [matinee](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/matinee) patrons."

The context is that all of those things are *shown on a screen,* to an audience which is paying for the right to see them. So, although the term "attraction" is ambiguous here (it literally just means a thing that attracts people, see [sense 4](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attraction)), it is reasonable to infer that it also means "something shown on a screen." Then, "hour-long" means that this attraction has a running time of (about) an hour.

An hour is too long to qualify as a [short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_film) even by the Academy's (very expansive) definition of "40 minutes or less, including credits," but modern [feature films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_film) are usually significantly longer than one hour, so that's probably why the author chose to describe it as an "hour-long attraction" instead of using a more familiar term such as "short" or "film." Also, it's being shown *in addition* to the main feature ("big picture"), so describing it as a "feature film" would be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

"An attraction" (in this context) is something which will attract customers.

In a theme park, an attraction could be a new roller coaster.  In a museum it might be a famous painting.  In a cinema it is a movie, or a type of movie.

In the 1930s, you didn't just go to the cinema to watch a movie. There was a cartoon (or several), a newsreel, and maybe a short film or documentary in addition to the main movie.

In response to the decline in audiences, the cinemas decided to add a longer, 1 hour, movie.  This would be shown in addition to the cartoons, short, and the main feature.